# AJAX not working (call php and get the result back)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to make a checkbox calls php code then get back the results to be printed in textarea.

Now, the problem is that the php file doesn't print the result on the textarea or maybe the Ajax not working. I am sure that there is nothing wrong with MySQL code.

this is form.php code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {

          var checkbox = document.getElementById('subscribers').checked;

         //Check if checkbox is checked
         if (checkbox === true) {
         //Read databank for Results
          document.getElementById("to").value = "result  should be here.";
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sms/readSubscriber.php',
                data: {'variable': dataPhp},
                complete: function(r){
                  var subscriberNumbers = r.responseText;
                   document.getElementById('to').innerHTML = subscriberNumbers;
               }
              });


         } else {
           document.getElementById("to").value = "";
         }


         }); 


         function doalert() {
         //Check if checkbox is checked
         var checkboxElem = document.getElementById("subscribers").checked;
         if (checkboxElem === true) {
         //Read databank for Results
          document.getElementById("to").value = "result  should be here.";
          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sms/readSubscriber.php',
                data: {'variable': dataPhp},
                complete: function(r){
                  var subscriberNumbers = r.responseText;
                   document.getElementById('to').innerHTML = subscriberNumbers;
               }
              });


         } else {
           document.getElementById("to").value = "";
         }

         }


      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <fieldset style="width:50%;margin:auto" dir=ltr>
         <form action="" method="POST">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
               <tr>
                  <td>Your Balance</td>
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="Balance" size="20" disabled="disabled" value="<?php
                     echo $Credits;
                     ?>"></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Mobile No.</td>
                  <td><textarea textarea class="form-control" id="to" name="Mobile" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea><br></td>
                  <td>
                     <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" value="subscribers"  onchange="doalert()" id="subscribers" checked>Subscribers</label>
                     </div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Message</td>
                  <td><textarea class="form-control" name="Text" cols="30" rows="5" required></textarea></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><input type="submit" name="Go" value="Send SMS" /></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </form>
      </fieldset>
   </body>
</html>
```

and this is the readSubscriber.php

```
<?php
require_once('../db_functions.php');

// Connect to the database
$connection = db_connect();
//if connection fails, stop script execution
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();

} else {

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM phoneSubscribers";
    // Query the database
    $result = db_isExist($query);

    if ($result) {
        $result = db_fetch($query);
        echo json_encode($result);
    } else {
        echo "No result";
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: You never declare dataPhp in ajax

Comment: Have you tried observing what happens using the developer tools in Chrome? E.g. is the Ajax request being fired, is it sent correctly, is the reply correct, etc.

Comment: Declare or set the variable properly and pass it through AJAX .

Comment: I don't know set variable to what? I don't want to pass values to php file. I just wanna retrive from php file. @PHP Web

Answer (score 0):

Set `value` of the `textArea` (instead of `innerHTML`)

Comment: Thanks I did it and got  undefined value in the textarea. @SandroKSG

Comment: @softwaredeveloper log `r` in your complete function: `console.log(r)`

Answer (score 0):

Change like this. It will works. You cannot replace variable ('variable') as value 
And You need to declare variable with value.

```
<script>
function doalert() {
  var checkboxElem = document.getElementById("subscribers").checked;
  if (checkboxElem === true) {
  //Read databank for Results
   document.getElementById("to").value = "result  should be here.";
   var dataPhp = '';
   $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'sms/readSubscriber.php',
         data: {variable: dataPhp},
         success : function(r){
           var subscriberNumbers = r.responseText;
            document.getElementById('to').innerHTML = subscriberNumbers;
        }
       });


  } else {
    document.getElementById("to").value = "";
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks I copied your code and replace innerHTML by value. I got undefined value in the textarea. @Madhan

Comment: Use network to see the response on Inspect element, Against this page (sms/readSubscriber.php)

Answer (score 0):

It done as I want

in my form:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        var checkboxElem = document.getElementById("subscribers").checked;
  if (checkboxElem === true) {
  //Read databank for Results

                var resp = $("#response");
                $.ajax({
                           type: 'POST',
                url: 'assets/php/readSubscriber.php',
                success: function(data) {
                     document.getElementById('to').value = data;

                }
                });



  } else {
    document.getElementById("to").value = "";
  }


         });



function doalert() {
  var checkboxElem = document.getElementById("subscribers").checked;
  if (checkboxElem === true) {
  //Read databank for Results

                var resp = $("#response");
                $.ajax({
                           type: 'POST',
                url: 'assets/php/readSubscriber.php',
                success: function(data) {
                     document.getElementById('to').value = data;

                }
                });



  } else {
    document.getElementById("to").value = "";
  }

}
```

in the called php file:

```
<?php
require_once('db_functions.php');

// Connect to the database
$connection = db_connect();
//if connection fails, stop script execution
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();

} else {

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM phoneSubscribers";
    // Query the database
    $result = db_isExist($query);

    if ($result) {
        $result   = db_fetch($query);
        $jsonData = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $jsonData[] = $row['phone'];

        }
        array_walk_recursive($jsonData, function($key, $value)
        {
            echo $key . ', ';
        });
    } else {

    }


}
?>
```